# What did I just commit to?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-proposals

I was just looking at the Lucene proposal on documentation and was considering committing, but I wanted to know what that actually *means*.

I figured that, as on Area 51, perhaps it tells you what you are committing to when you click the button (which, come to think, maybe that isn't so fantastic either), and gives you a chance to back out:

[image: Commitment explanation on Area 51]

But nope, not this time. I clicked the commit button, and it's done, and irrevocable as far as I can tell. And *I still don't know what I've gotten myself into!* Have I just committed to contribute X new topics in the documentation? Actively participate for Y days/months/years?  Sacrifice a fatted calf?

So, what *have* I just gotten myself into?

Comment: Seems to me like you haven't committed to *do* anything, you've just lent your vote that a topic proposal is valid and the topic should be created.

Comment: @MartinCarney If the topic got created, yet none of the "contributors" who agreed to it actually contributed anything, what's the value of creating the topic? Surely people who commit to a topic should intend to document it too.

Comment: @PetahChristian Oh I agree, people who commit to a topic should definitely contribute to it. But since committing doesn't have a specified set of actions that OP is supposed to do like Area51 does, OP hasn't explicitly committed to *do* anything. OP *should* contribute, but it isn't clearly defined *how* or *how much*.

Comment: Stack Overflow now owns your soul. Thank you for your business.

Comment: One of us! One of us! One of us!

Comment: https://tech.slashdot.org/story/16/07/13/2010231/tos-agreements-require-giving-up-first-born----and-users-gladly-consent

Comment: Remember, creating / shutting down Documentation for a tag has orders of magnitude less overhead than creating/killing a whole site. I suspect this is just a "are there at least a few people in this tag who have some level of interest in Docs" check.