# Let us un-commit from a Documentation Tag proposal

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

I accidentally committed to the [toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toggle) proposal while viewing questions with that tag. I just clicked to view the proposal in the sidebar - I knew there was already docs in [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jquery/1298/element-visibility/12641/toggle-possibilities#t=201607271718553349333) but I didn't intend to commit, I meant to exit and it was a slip!

It should be possible to revoke a commit - could some of the mods look into this (in general, but pm if you could undo this instance? :) )

I only saw [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329018/what-did-i-just-commit-to) just now - there must be (many?) others in the same boat.

Support please!

Comment: A tooltip explaining what *Commit*  is for would also help. Have done same thing trying to understand the UI

Comment: @charlietfl yep, v good suggestion!

Comment: Agree with the sentiment, but I don't think it's a bug

Comment: @Flexo fair enough, it is early days..

Comment: You want to make commitment a _toggle_?

Comment: There's a balance to be struck here between "no, you really need to commit and not bail at the last second" and "yeahhhh misclicks happen". I'll see about making it clearer what's about to happen and when. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear Maybe something similar to how up/down votes work? Of course, the 5 minute time frame may need tweaking...

Comment: @Laurel 5-minutes should be good enough to handle the "oh crap, I misclicked" cases. I need to take a closer look at the proposal workflow overall to make sure we're not misrepresenting what's about to happen (vs an actual accidental click on behalf of the user), but outside of that... an "undo" button should do it. We'll see about the sanest way to implement this in the short term.

Comment: @AdamLear 5 mins is plenty - i needed about 5 secs!