# Express an interest in the Tag Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals, documentation-tags

According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-add-tags

> In order for a tag to have documentation, it must have at least 500
>   questions and 10 committed users with at least 150 reputation and 1
>   positively scored answer in a tag .

According to comments to [What did I just commit to?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329018/what-did-i-just-commit-to)
commit is actually a vote to create the documentation for the tag (available to users with some knowledge of the tag).
Should it just be named "Vote to create the tag"?

I found windows-azure-storage Documentation Proposal https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/windows-azure-storage, but there is no way  to say that I want to have such documentation.

What to do if I don't have positively scored answer in the tag but want to see documentation, because I fill that vendor documentation is not good enough?

What to do if I have an idea for an example, but the tag is a proposal yet?

1. I suggest to have an option  **"Vote to create the tag?"** that will be allowed for any user. Users with the proved knowledge in the tag can have bigger number of votes.
   For example, to create a tag it would be required 10 normal votes, but vote of the user with at least 1 positively scored answer in the tag considered as 2 normal (the actual figures can be different).
   Minimum requirement of 500 questions can be decreased/removed if number of votes exceed 15 (again numbers can be different)
2. Another button **"Register for  contribution"**  should be added and when proposal will be approved, the user will receive notification, that tag is ready for topics/examples creation. Number of people wanting to contribute also should be considered when tag is open for documentation.

Comment: You're using your terms wrong. "Topics" exist within a "tag". You commit to "tag"s, not "topics". Windows Azure Storage is a *tag*, not a topic.

Comment: @NicolBolas: thanks, indeed I mixed them. I've rewrote the suggestion to use Tag term correctly